# White bar appearing on the right side in a website?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

There is a white bar appearing on the right side of the screen of a website in mobile view and also in laptop view. I am trying to use inspect to solve this problem.

This is the website:

```
https://etradewealth.com/main.html
```

You can inspect and make changes in css etc. My first question is can anyone inspect the website and tell what changes to make in css?

I have used this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

My second question is am I missing something in this meta tag?

Comment: please add your actual code not link

Comment: Your owl-stage div is set at 9807px, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is in your Videos Section after `<div class="video-area-tablecell">` you have `<div class="row">`.

As you know "row" class has negative margin, please add "col-md-12" class in the `<div class="video-area-tablecell">` div to cover the negative margin.

Thanks me later.